# How to write makefile using ifort compiler?

Tags: compiler-errors, makefile, fortran, intel-fortran

I was using the makefile code (below), with a Fortran77 compiler it worked to my satisfaction but I attempted to use the same code in partnership with an Intel Fortran Compiler (IFORT) and it does not work well at all.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on improving the code?

```
OBJ = change.o twopt.o ddmath.o cklib.o
f77 = pgf77 
opt = -O4        
.f.o:   
        $(f77) $(opt) -c $*.f
stagdri: $(OBJ)
        pgf77  -o change.exe $(OBJ)
        strip change.exe
```

Comment: Well... what did you try?  And what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Can you add the current edited makefile you are using to your post?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty simple makefile and the only real change needed is to change `f77 = pfg77` to `f77 = ifort`.  I'm not sure that ifort will like the `-O4` option (O3 is the highest level in documentation for ifort), so you might change that just to make sure you get optimization.

There are two other issues not related to the makefile that could be causing you problems.

1. The intel compilers run on the command line require that you run a script to setup the intel environment.  Make sure you are running that script before making the project.  On linux this is `source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64` for the 64 bit environment and default installation path.
2. ifort can be quite picky in some ways and reject code that is accepted by pgf or gfortran.  You may need to tighten up your code or find compiler arguments to relax the compiler, where applicable.

To provide any specific help beyond these generalities, the actual errors produced by the compiler or by make need to be provided.

Comment: Thank you for my information. But I still can not get it work...when I "make -f makexx", it shows the message:
O4         -c check.f
make: O4: Command not found
make: [check.o] Error 127 (ignored)
ifort  -o check.exe check.o twopt.o ddmath.o cklib.o
make: ifort: Command not found
make: *** [stagdri] Error 127
I don't know if it is the problem of compiler?

Comment: @user3758608 Those errors look like youve messed up the f77 variable (It would help to see the actual makefile you are using). The second error is due to not finding the compiler.  Have you initialized the intel environment (See bullet #1 in my answer)?